# Solve $y=xy'-((y')^5+40y'+\sin(y'))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to take derivative each side but at the end,

I ended up with $x=5(y')^4+40+\cos(y')$

because $y''$ were cancelled out. I m stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called Clairaut ODE. You actually get two ODEs. One is $y''=0 \implies y'=C$. Put thois in the original ODE to get the general solution as
$$y=Cx-C^5-40 C-\sin C,~~~~~(1)$$
which a familly of lines when the parameter $C$ is varied. The solution of
$$x=5y'^4+40+\cos(y') ~~~~(2)$$ will be a fixed curve (without a constant) which will be envelope of the family of lines given by (1). in fact for any value of $C$ the line woll touch this fixed curve. But (2) ids difficult to solve by hand.

I may get back again.